# Modifying R packages (snow)

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Can anybody give me some direction on editing source code of an R package? From what I've seen, changing the package from within R does not seem to be possible. In editing outside of R, I'm stuck at unpacking the tar.gz. While I can now modify the function to my heart's content, the folder looks nothing like the working snow library. I presume I will need to turn the contents into a tar.gz once again and install it in the standard way?

My colleagues and I have been attempting to get `makeSOCKcluster()` to work with remote IPs for the past three days. Hangs indefinitely. After digging into the snow package I've found the issue to be in the way `newSOCKnode()` calls `socketConnection()`. If I run `makeSOCKcluster("IP", manual=T)` and then put the output into powershell, it results in the connection being made but the program not completing. However, I can run `makeSOCKcluster("IP", manual=T)` in one R instance and then run `system("output", wait=F, input="")` in another instance which results in the program completing. I believe I can simply modify snow to do this automatically.

Comment: File->New Project->Existing Directory Then when you are done do Build->Build and Reload [Developing Packages with RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486488-Developing-Packages-with-RStudio)

Comment: You can edit any source code you have on your machine.  Your question is unclear.  Further, how about you try asking specifically how to get `snow` to do what you want? It's quite possible there are options available in the existing package.

Comment: Extract source code (tar.gz -> tar) into a folder. R code is in the (drumroll) R/ subfolder. Once you're done, you'll need to compile the package. See the [comprehensive manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html). Since you already have a constructed package, you only modify things and change bits here and there.

Comment: Thanks, Livid! Had to play with some options but that did the trick.